# Cannot get data from two tables using join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

First table: Product

```
id | Name | Price | Discount
-------------------------------
1    xyz     200
2    xyz     250
3    yz      100     50
```

Second table : buy

```
id  | userid  |  Product_id  Card_details  
------------------------------------------
1       1           1          55555   
2       1           2          88888      
3       3           1          77777
```

Now i have $user_id in my php variable. If user id is 3 i want following output:

```
id   Name   Price   Discount     user_id    Product_id   Card_details

3     yz     100      50            3           1           77777
```

How can i achieve this.

Comment: anyone of us can give you this ans in a blink of eye, but thats not what SO is for. we help you correct your mistakes. show us what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Product JOIN buy ON Product.id = buy.id WHERE buy.userid = $user_id`;

Comment: If i want only selected column from buy table or no column then where i need to do the changes.

Comment: Specify whatever columns you need in `SELECT`
like `SELECT Product.id, buy.userid, buy.Product_id, ....`

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN` or `where`

```
 SELECT * FROM Product p JOIN buy b 
 ON p.id = b.Product_id 
 WHERE b.userid ='3'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `SELECT * FROM Product` **AS** `p JOIN buy` **AS** `b ON p.id = b.product_id WHERE b.userid = '3'`?

Comment: @lino In most DBMSs, you specify column aliases with `AS`, and table aliases without. I'm sure there's a reason for that.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax ok, didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

```
$query = "SELECT Product.id, Product.Name, Product.Price, Product.Discount,
buy.userid , buy.Product_id, buy.Card_details
FROM Product
JOIN buy ON Product.id = buy.Product_id
WHERE buy.userid = 3";
```

Answer (score 1):

First in your Product table xyz is to time you have to use unique name for your product for better understanding.

Now in Product table id is your product id. Check your Buys tables productid there is no entry for product id 3. When you want to buy product 3 for user id 3 then buy table productid entry should be three for userid 3.

Now check the below query it will definitely work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM Product 
INNER JOIN buy ON Product.id = buy.Product_id
WHERE buy.userid = '3';
```

It means you want to get product buy by userid 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @USER_ID INT=3 --I/P of USER_ID
SELECT P.ID,
       P.NAME,
       P.PRICE,
       P.Discount,
       B.user_id,
       B.PRODUCT_ID,
       B.CARD_DETAILS
FROM   #PRODUCT P
       JOIN #BUY B
         ON P.ID = B.ID
WHERE  B.USER_ID = @USER_ID
```